# Number of black rows in a table

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $4$ rows and $3$ columns in a table, and each slot is painted with black or white with equal probability, and I wish to find the probability that one, and only one of the rows is painted black. What I did was:
$$P= 4\cdot (1/2)^3 * (7/8)^3=\frac{343}{1024}$$
and it indeed seems to be the correct answer. I thought I should also try solving it using combinatorics, but that is something I fail to do. My try is:
$$\frac{4\cdot 1\cdot(2^9-7)}{2^{12}}=\frac{505}{1024}\neq\frac{343}{1024}$$

Explanation: There is one possibility for the first row to be black, and that is multiplied by the total number of possibilities for the other $3$ rows, while subtracting the possibilities they contain at least one black row. All is multiplied by $4$ - the number of rows and of course divided by the total number of possibilities. That doesn't seem to work, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that $\displaystyle (2^9-7) \ $ does not count where *each* of the remaining three rows cannot be painted all black.

It should rather be $\displaystyle (2^3-1)^3 \ $ permutations for the remaining three rows. Each row can be painted in $2^3$ ways but one of those is where all columns are black and we subtract that.

So the answer should be,

$\displaystyle \ \frac{4 \cdot 1 \cdot (2^3-1)^3}{2^{12}} \ $

Answer (score 0):

Math Lover's (direct) approach is clearly more elegant than the following:  I can't resist applying [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to the problem.

Since there are $(4 \times 3) = 12$ cells, when expressing the probability as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

you have that $D = 2^{(12)}.$

Therefore, the problem reduces to identifying $(N) = $ the number of ways that the $(12)$ cells can be painted so that there is exactly $(1)$ black row.

Here, $N$ may be computed as $A - B$, where

$A = $ the number of ways that there is **at least** 1 black row and

$B = $ the number of ways that there are **at least** 2 black rows.

I will use Inclusion-Exclusion to calculate $A,B$.

---

$\underline{\text{Calculation of } ~A}$

Given any set $F$ with a finite number of elements, 
let $|F|$ denote the number of elements in $F$.

Let $R_i ~: ~i \in \{1,2,3,4\}~$ denote the set of paintings that represent row $R_i$ being painted black, with the other $9$ cells unconstrained.

Let $T_1 = \sum_{i=1}^4 |R_i|.$ 
Let $T_2 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4} |R_i \cap R_j|.$ 
Let $T_3 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4} |R_i \cap R_j \cap R_k|.$ 
Let $T_4 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k < l \leq 4} |R_i \cap R_j \cap R_k \cap R_l|.$

Then

$$A = T_1 - T_2 + T_3 - T_4.$$

To calculate $T_1$, consider that for $R_1$, there are 9 cells unconstrained.  
Therefore, $|R_1| = 2^{9}.$  
Therefore, by symmetry:
$T_1 = 4 \times 2^{9} = 2048.$

To calculate $T_2$, consider that for $(R_1 \cap R_2)$, there are 6 cells unconstrained. 
Therefore, $|R_1 \cap R_2| = 2^{6}.$  
Therefore, by symmetry:
$T_2 = \binom{4}{2} \times 2^{6} = 384.$

To calculate $T_3$, consider that for $(R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3)$, there are 3 cells unconstrained. 
Therefore, $|R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3| = 2^{3}.$  
Therefore, by symmetry:
$T_3 = \binom{4}{3} \times 2^{3} = 32.$

To calculate $T_4$, consider that for $(R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3 \cap R_4)$, there are 0 cells unconstrained. 
Therefore, $|R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3 \cap R_4| = 2^{0} = 1.$ 
Therefore:
$T_4 = \binom{4}{4} \times 1 = 1.$

Therefore,

$$A = T_1 - T_2 + T_3 - T_4 = 2048 - 384 + 32 - 1 = 1695.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Calculation of } ~B}$

Adopting the $R_i$ syntax of the previous section, you have 6 sets to consider:

Set $Q_1 = (R_1 \cap R_2).$ 
Set $Q_2 = (R_1 \cap R_3).$ 
Set $Q_3 = (R_1 \cap R_4).$ 
Set $Q_4 = (R_2 \cap R_3).$ 
Set $Q_5 = (R_2 \cap R_4).$ 
Set $Q_6 = (R_3 \cap R_4).$

Let $S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^6 |Q_i|.$ 
Let $S_2 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 6} |Q_i \cap Q_j|.$ 
Let $S_3 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 6} |Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k|.$ 
Let $S_4 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k < l \leq 6} |Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k \cup Q_l|.$ 
Let $S_5 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k < l < m \leq 6} |Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k \cup Q_l  \cup Q_m|.$ 
Let $S_6 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k < l < m < n \leq 6} |Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k \cup Q_l \cup Q_m \cup Q_n|.$

Then

$$B = S_1 - S_2 + S_3 - S_4 + S_5 - S_6.$$

To calculate $S_1$, consider that for $Q_1 = (R_1 \cap R_2)$, there are 6 cells unconstrained.  
Therefore, $|Q_1| = 2^{6}.$  
Therefore, by symmetry:
$S_1 = \binom{6}{1} \times 2^{6} = 384.$

Calculating $S_2$ is complicated. 
Of the $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ possible intersections $(Q_i \cap Q_j)$, 
exactly $3$ of them will have $0$ cells unconstrained: 
namely $(Q_1 \cap Q_6), (Q_2 \cap Q_5),$ and $(Q_3 \cap Q_4).$ 
The other $12$ intersections will each have $3$ unconstrained cells.
Therefore:
$S_2 = \left[~\left(12 \times 2^{3}\right) ~+~
\left(3 \times 1\right) ~\right] 
~=~ 99.$

Similarly, to calculate $S_3$: 
Of the $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ possible intersections $(Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k)$, 
exactly $4$ of them will have $3$ cells unconstrained: 
namely $(Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap Q_4), (Q_1 \cap Q_3 \cap Q_5), (Q_2 \cap Q_3 \cap Q_6)$ and $(Q_4 \cap Q_5 \cap Q_6).$ 
The other $16$ intersections will each have $0$ unconstrained cells.
Therefore:
$S_3 = \left[~\left(4 \times 2^{3}\right) ~+~
\left(16 \times 1\right) ~\right] 
~=~ 48.$

To calculate $S_4$: 
Of the $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ possible intersections $(Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k \cap Q_l)$, 
all of them will have $0$ cells unconstrained.
Therefore:
$S_4 = 15.$

To calculate $S_5$: 
Of the $\binom{6}{5} = 6$ possible intersections $(Q_i \cap Q_j \cap Q_k \cap Q_l \cap Q_m)$, 
all of them will have $0$ cells unconstrained.
Therefore:
$S_5 = 6.$

To calculate $S_6$: 
The sole relevant intersection, $(Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap Q_3 \cap Q_4 \cap Q_5 \cap Q_6)$, 
will have $0$ cells unconstrained.
Therefore:
$S_6 = 1.$

Therefore,

$$B = S_1 - S_2 + S_3 - S_4 + S_5 - S_6 = 
384 - 99 + 48 - 15 + 6 - 1 = 323.$$

---

Final computation:

$$N = 1695 - 323 = 1372 \implies \frac{N}{D} = 
\frac{1372}{4096} = \frac{343}{1024}.$$